# waze deep links - can't build url with multiple stops, is it possible?

Tags: waze

I want to use waze deep links to open a route with multiple stops.

One stop, of course, is easy.

https://waze.com/ul?ll=51.80308,-0.04868&navigate=yes

But there appears to be nothing in the docs to say if this is possible or not, you can chain params, but I've tried a few combinations and cant seem to make it work.

Can anyone advise?

Equivalent in google maps would be

[https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=51.75965,-0.01041&destination=51.75965,-0.01041&waypoints=51.75202,-0.01414|51.80308,-0.04868|51.80137,-0.07178|51.6801,-0.05181|51.72913,0.07556|51.73573,0.09298|51.84566,0.0537|51.78428,0.1363|51.6448,-0.07145|51.86966,0.1625|51.77342,-0.22581|51.78601,-0.00261|51.75729,-0.47633|51.78115,-0.0432&dir_action=navigate](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=51.75965,-0.01041&destination=51.75965,-0.01041&waypoints=51.75202,-0.01414%7C51.80308,-0.04868%7C51.80137,-0.07178%7C51.6801,-0.05181%7C51.72913,0.07556%7C51.73573,0.09298%7C51.84566,0.0537%7C51.78428,0.1363%7C51.6448,-0.07145%7C51.86966,0.1625%7C51.77342,-0.22581%7C51.78601,-0.00261%7C51.75729,-0.47633%7C51.78115,-0.0432&dir_action=navigate)

Comment: Did you figure out a solution? Thanks

Comment: No sorry, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there's no way to achieve this. ATM, Waze only allows 1 stop and beside that, there's no deeplink implemented to do that.

You can check waze official forums for more info. There're several posts about that.

https://www.waze.com/forum/search.php